# Passing Multiple Value a href and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am beginner in PHP. I have one table it value fetching mysql. There is a `share` field it `a href` and also I have one text box ..  so  i just click share i want get both value ...  but my code not working properly. it working only first row in the table.  i just click second row but not passing text box value

check my code here...

```
$attchquery= mysql_query("select * from eduploads order by id desc limit 5") ; echo "
<table style='width:100%' class='table'>" ; echo "
    <tr>" ; echo "
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>FileSize</th>
        <th>Attachemnt Code</th>
        <th>File Link</th>
        <th>Share</th>" ; echo "</tr>" ; $count = 0 ; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($attchquery)) { $count++ ; echo "
    <tr>" ; echo "
        <td>",$count,"</td>
        <td>",$row['filedate'],"</td>
        <td>", $row['filename'].".".$row['fileext'],"
        </td>
        <td>", $row['filesize'],"
        </td>
        <td>",$row['fileid'],"</td>
        <td>", "
            <a href='".$valueres[' settingsvalue '],$row['filelink ']."'>Download</a></td>
        <td>", "
            <a id='the-link' href='?id=".$row[' fileaddname ']."' class='btn btn-primary'>Share</a>
        </td>" ; echo "</tr>" ; } echo "</table>" ; ?>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="singleemail" id="singleemail" value="testvaluepossing">
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('the-link').onclick = function(e) {
        var singleemail = document.getElementById('singleemail').value;
        document.location.href = this.href + '&singleemail=' + singleemail;
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

How does this work?  Please Give Good Solution or Examples..

Comment: Your question is unclear, from what i understood you want to get the `href` of share link along with the submitted form? If that's the case, create a `type="hidden"` input with the link as value when generating the share link and it will get submitted

Comment: **NOTICE:** Don't use [mysql_*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) functions in new code, `mysql` extension it is deprecated and has been for years and is removed forever in PHP7.0+. If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements. [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You have the same value of `id` for all your `Share` anchors, so your code only assigns an `onclick` event to the first of them.